# How to render a material-ui input control instead a textfield for materials-ui-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-tsx

In my React (v16.3) app I am rendering date-picker controls using *material-ui-pickers* library's DatePicker component. This component renders a Material-UI [`TextField`](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/#textfield) component. I like to change this so it renders only a Material-UI [`Input`](https://material-ui-next.com/api/input/) without the chrome rendered by `TextField`.

As I understood one can to this with the DatePickers `TextFieldComponent` field ([here](https://material-ui-pickers.firebaseapp.com/demo/datetimepicker) at the bottom) but I couldn't figure out how to use this field.

```
 <DatePicker 
     id={name}
     TextFieldComponent={...<HOW_TO> ...}
     value={value} 
     onChange={this.handleChange}
     disabled={isReadOnly} />
```

Any ideas how to do this?

**Update:**
Got one step further by finding the right syntax to use and not its rendering without the chrome (`FormControl`, `InputLabel`, etc.). But also no DatePicker is opened anymore. Do I have to open it programmatically?

```
<DatePicker 
    id={name}
    TextFieldComponent={(props) => this.renderInput(props)}
    value={value} 
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    disabled={isReadOnly} />
```

And here is renderInput():

```
renderInput(props: TextFieldProps): any {
   return ( <Input
     id={props.id}
     value={props.value}
     onChange={this.handleChange}
     type={'text'}
     disabled={props.disabled}
   /> );
 }
```

Comment: Are you using latest version? material-ui@next?
If latest, try:
inputComponent union: string |
 func
The component used for the native input. Either a string to use a DOM element or a component.

Comment: I use the latest vnext material-ui and material-ui-pickers. I can't see anything called 'inputComponent'. Only 'TextFieldComponent'.

Comment: Got it what you mean. That's exactly what I try to do but without success. Got it running to the point it only renders the input but now no data-picker is shown anymore. I guess I need to open it grammatically. See "update".

Comment: Try adding `onClick={props.onClick}` to your `Input` component.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Updated October 2020**

#### @material-ui/pickers v3.x (latest)

To render an `Input` instead of a `TextField` component, you can pass a custom component to the `TextFieldComponent` prop on `DatePicker`.

You will need to pass along the following props to the `Input`: `value`, `onChange`, and `onClick`.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Input, TextFieldProps } from "@material-ui/core";
import { DatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import { MaterialUiPickersDate } from "@material-ui/pickers/typings/date";

export default function Demo() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<MaterialUiPickersDate>(
    new Date()
  );

  const renderInput = (props: TextFieldProps): any => (
    <Input
      type="text"
      onClick={props.onClick}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.onChange}
    />
  );

  return (
    <DatePicker
      label="Basic example"
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={setSelectedDate}
      TextFieldComponent={renderInput}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material UI Pickers Example]

#### @material-ui/pickers v4.0.0-alpha12 (next)

NOTE: v4 is currently in alpha, so the API might change in the future.

In V4, you use the `renderInput` prop on `DatePicker` to customize the input ([see docs](https://v4-0-0-alpha-12.material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker#custom-input-component)). The following example renders a material ui `Input` instead of a `TextField`.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Input, TextFieldProps } from "@material-ui/core";
import { DatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";

export default function Demo() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<Date | null>(new Date());

  const renderInput = (props: TextFieldProps): any => (
    <Input
      type="text"
      inputRef={props.inputRef}
      inputProps={props.inputProps}
      value={props.value}
      onClick={props.onClick}
      onChange={props.onChange}
      endAdornment={props.InputProps?.endAdornment}
    />
  );

  return (
    <DatePicker
      label="Basic example"
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={setSelectedDate}
      renderInput={renderInput}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material UI Pickers v4 Example]

Comment: The Code Sandbox is returning an error at the moment

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! This answer was written in 2018 so it refers to older versions of Material UI and Material UI Pickers. The CodeSandbox demo needs to be rebuilt using current versions of those libraries. I temporarily removed the link while I work on updating it.

Comment: @LukePeavey you ever get around to figuring out how this is done with current API? It's giving me a lot of trouble with `"@material-ui/pickers": "^4.0.0-alpha.9"`

Comment: @Murcielago I'll take a look at it this weekend and see if I can update it for current versions of material-ui.

Comment: @Murcielago I updated my answer and added a new sandbox demo that uses the latest version of both libraries. Let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: @Murcielago Sorry just realized you were asking about v4 alpha. I will take a look at the v4 API tomorrow and add a second example

Comment: @Murcielago I added an example using @material-ui/pickers 4.0.0-alpha

Comment: Hi @Luke Peavey, sorry to bother you. I'm trying to achieve this. Everything is working fine except that my picker is getting displayed out of place. I have this error : "Material-UI: The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid". Do you have any idea? Thanks for your help

Comment: @NicolasOuldBouamama Not sure what would be causing that. It's hard to say without seeing your code. I would suggest creating a new question for this. Id be happy to take a look at it!

Comment: @LukePeavey thanks for your answer. I just found that using TextFieldComponent with "inline" variant is causing the issue with v3.x so I changed the variant to "dialog" and now everything is working fine. Thanks anyways

Comment: @NicolasOuldBouamama glad you were able to figure it out